# How to read sqlite data using C++.?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I want to read sqlite database file using c++ and VS2010 and i am writing below code.

```
sqlite3 *db;
int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
```

I am getting this kind of error

```
lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _strncmp already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(strncmp.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgmalloc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgfree.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrealloc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(memmove.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) : error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(atox.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>output\win32\Debug\SC.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I did included sqlite3.lib in project and had given path ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your project, you are trying to use both the DEBUG version and the RELEASE (NON-DEBUG) version of the C standard library.

This means that sqlite3.lib is using one kind of C standard library, and your project is using another. Your project, and the used libraries must match the Debug/Release choice, and the Static/Dynamic use of Standard Library choice.

Comment: @Vaghani can avoid this including `sqlite3.c` instead of `sqlite3.lib`.

Comment: You mean sqlite3.c in additional dependency instead of sqlite3.lib..?

Comment: No. Keep sqlite3.lib. The issue is that sqlite3.lib depends on one type of the C standard libraries. To be able to use sqlite3.lib into your project, then your project must use the same C standard library type that sqlite3.lib uses.

Comment: @DidierTrosset So is there any other library you know about that reads sqlite data with c++..?

Comment: You can download the amalgation source and build it yourself, then you can make one release lib and one debug build, and link them depending on your build. An old blog post about this: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/09/23/compiling-sqlite-on-windows/

Comment: @Didier Trosset : After working for many hours i found the solution. thanks for the idea...